# Using Qt network module in a plugin (DLL)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm writing a plugin for a large, non-Qt Windows application ([Autodesk 3ds Max](http://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview)). The plugin is a native DLL written in C++11.

I would like my plugin to check for updates by querying GitHub's HTTP API using Qt 4.8.7 networking component.

I've tried a simple test but the `QNetworkAccessManager::get()` call hangs forever:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://api.github.com/repos/appleseedhq/appleseed-max/releases")));
QByteArray result = reply->readAll();
```

I suppose this is because I don't have a Qt event loop running.

What's the right way to proceed here? Do I need a `QtApplication`? Given that I'm writing a plugin and not an application, how should I structure things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve it is to launch new QThread derived object from the DLL exported function and to run the event thread in there:

```
    // Mind the files. For MOC compiler to create signals and slots
    // we need the class to be declared in the header file.

    // MyThread.h 
    // Include missing headers
    class MyThread : public QThread
    {
      Q_OBJECT
      protected:
         void run(); // override

      public slots:
         void readData();
         void requestFinished(QNetworkReply * reply);
    };

    void MyThread::run() // override
    {
        // TODO: make it to quit the loop with some signal
        // initialize other objects before the loop
        QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
        // we want manager object to run on this thread
        manager->moveToThread(this); // the call maybe redundant here

        connect(manager , SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

        QEventLoop loop;
        loop.exec();
    }

    // MyThread.cpp
    #include "MyThread.h"
    void MyThread::readData(QString strUrl)
    {
       // mind how exactly you compose the request (?)
       QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(strUrl));

       // here: usually this 'get' request is done from some slot while already in event loop
       QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
       // or maybe post request
       // QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request);

       // Error handling
       // connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
       //   this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
       // connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
       //   this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
   }

   void MyThread::requestFinished(QNetworkReply * reply)
   {
      QByteArray result = pReply->readAll();

      // do something with result
      pCallBack(result);
   }


   // MyDll.h
   __declspec(dllexport) void dllFunctionStart();
   // reading new data may depend on your app logic
   __declspec(dllexport) void dllFunctionRequestData();

   // MyDll.cpp 
    #include "MyDll.h"
    #include "MyThread.h"

    static MyThread* s_pThread;

    __declspec(dllexport) void dllFunctionStart()
    {
        // TODO: take care of releasing the thread object on quitting the thread
        s_pThread = new MyThread;
        s_pThread->start();
    }

    // reading new data may depend on your app logic
    __declspec(dllexport) void dllFunctionRequestData()
    {
        if (s_pThread)
            s_pThread->readData();
    }
```

P.S. I did not compile that but that is how this task is usually solved. Mind the to-dos.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that certainly helps. Unfortunately `QNetworkAccessManager::get()` still hangs. Here are the callstacks of the two relevant threads: http://pastebin.com/UCi4nMt9

Comment: I suspect the request being out of scope. Please see the corrected code. Also mind files where you put the code in. With Qt 4 no way around but you need to have the header for signals and slots to work with new class.

Comment: Yes, I moc'ed the header file and linked against the resulting .cpp file. I think my code was correct, and I suspect it's actually a known Qt bug (see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26355), [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-24554) and [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79785) for various similar occurrences). While the problem might be fixed in later versions of Qt, I'm stuck with 4.8.7. Your answer is helpful so I accepted it. In the end I've decided to use plain Win32 functions since I have no portability requirements.

Comment: Huh, we use Qt 5.3.2 QNetworkManager really intensively. So many cycles through QA already. Bad that you stuck with older Qt.